# add an encrypted password of an Entity in a database using Bcrypt + Hibernate + SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, entity, bcrypt, password-encryption, hibernate-annotations

Maybe it simple but I would like to know how can I proceed to encrypt a password before store it in my database. 
Below my Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "t_connexion" )
@SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
public class T_connexion implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long      id;

@Column( name = "email" )
private String    email;

@Column( name = "password" )
private String    password;


@Transient
private String    confirmation;

@Column( name = "nomUtilisateur" )
private String    nomUtilisateur;

@Column( name = "date_inscription" )
private Timestamp dateInsription = new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() );
//......
}
```

Using annotations store automatically the password before performing any operation.

I would like to keep using annotations but encrypt my password before store it.

How can I proceed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it's really simple to solve this.

Just using the setter method of the password property before storing it in the database.